# Having trouble connecting usb wifi adapter to Virtualbox VM

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, network-adapter, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver

I have a Techkey wifi adapter that i'm trying to connect to my kali linux virtual machine. I'm getting into ethical hacking and I need a wireless interface as opposed to ethernet. This wifi adapter works perfectly on my windows host machine and i've tested it and it works perfectly on my linux pc. I never needed to install drivers on an computer in order for it to work, its been a plug and play experience. I have tried just about every possible way that I found online to connect the adapter to my VM. I tried adding it to usb devices. And yes I have the virtual box extension package.

The out put of `lsusb` for this device is `ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL88x2bu [AC1200 Techkey]`

If this is a driver issue I have a usb drive that the adapter came with. The driver is `RTL8812BU`

Comment: So what is the actual problem you're encountering (doesn't show up in VirtualBox, doesn't show up in Kali, can't get a connection, etc.)? Are you encountering any error message (Windows, VirtualBox, Kali). Please [edit] your question to clarify the exact steps you're taking and the issues you're encountering.

Comment: See if this driver (apparently tested in Kali Linux) works for you:   ..... https://www.fastoe.com/blog/install-rtl8812bu-usb-wifi-dongle-on-linux